# How can i set the value of particular indexs item name in input field in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Here what happening is when i click on edittask at that time that task name should be set in the input value and its setting value as (object object) but i want to set the task name instead of it. can anyone help me with that.

[this is what i am getting in console when i click on edit button and what its setting the value in input box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV37D.png)

```js
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            newTaskTitle: "",
            isEditing : false
        }
    },
    props:{
        Task:{
            type:Array,
            required: true
        },
    },
    methods:{
        removeTask: function(idx){
            this.Index = idx;
            this.$emit('remove',this.Index);
        },
        EditTaskI(tsk){
            this.task = tsk;
            console.log(this.task);
            this.isEditing = this.isEditing == true ? false : true;
            this.newTaskTitle = this.task;
        },
        TaskUpdated(){
            this.isEditing = this.isEditing == true ? false : true;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <section v-if="Task.length > 0" class="taskMainSection">
        <section v-for="(tasks,index) in Task" :key="index" class="sectionTask" >
            <section class="TaskBox" v-if="!isEditing">
                <div class="TaskTitleList" >
                    <div class="TaskSection">
                            <p class="listTask">{{ tasks.Task }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="OptionSectionMain">
                    <div class="OptionSection">
                            <p class="removeTask fa fa-close" @click="removeTask(index)"></p>
                            <p class="editTask fa fa-edit" @click="EditTaskI(tasks)"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="TaskBoxEdit" v-else>
                <div class="TaskTitleList" >
                    <div class="TaskSection">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" :value="newTaskTitle">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="OptionSectionMain">
                    <div class="OptionSection">
                            <p class="removeTask fa fa-check" @click="TaskUpdated"></p>
                    </div>                   
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            newTaskTitle: "",
            isEditing : false
        }
    },
    props:{
        Task:{
            type:Array,
            required: true
        },
    },
    methods:{
        removeTask: function(idx){
            this.Index = idx;
            this.$emit('remove',this.Index);
        },
        EditTaskI(tsk){
            this.task = tsk;
            console.log(this.task);
            this.isEditing = this.isEditing == true ? false : true;
            this.newTaskTitle = this.task;
        },
        TaskUpdated(){
            this.isEditing = this.isEditing == true ? false : true;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <section v-if="Task.length > 0" class="taskMainSection">
        <section v-for="(tasks,index) in Task" :key="index" class="sectionTask" >
            <section class="TaskBox" v-if="!isEditing">
                <div class="TaskTitleList" >
                    <div class="TaskSection">
                            <p class="listTask">{{ tasks.Task }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="OptionSectionMain">
                    <div class="OptionSection">
                            <p class="removeTask fa fa-close" @click="removeTask(index)"></p>
                            <!--In below line just need to change "tasks.task" on the place of "tasks"  -->
                            <p class="editTask fa fa-edit" @click="EditTaskI(tasks)"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="TaskBoxEdit" v-else>
                <div class="TaskTitleList" >
                    <div class="TaskSection">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" :value="newTaskTitle">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="OptionSectionMain">
                    <div class="OptionSection">
                            <p class="removeTask fa fa-check" @click="TaskUpdated"></p>
                    </div>                   
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</template>
```